# Inline assembler: flags — to save or not to save

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, assembly, intel, inline-assembly

The question is about both **GCC** and **Visual Studio** inline assemblers for Intel processors.

It's not clear to me whether I should save FLAGS (EFLAGS/RFLAGS) register somehow. Does compiler ever rely on already-set flags to, for example, avoid two comparisons or something (with or without optimisations)?

Comment: No.  Just reset the DF flag if you ever tinker with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 types of flags in the EFLAGS register:

- Status Flags
- Control Flags
- System Flags

It is clear that you cannot change the System Flags unless you are writing a driver so not much of a concern here.

There is one Control flags, DF, as mentioned by others. You want that flag to remain the same way as it was. DF is used by the "string" instructions such as MOVS (now renamed streaming instructions.)

The status flags (OF, SF, ZF, AF, PF, CF), I have not yet seen a C/C++ compiler that makes use of the status flags on return. So for "standard functions," status flags can be anything on return. (i.e. low level in a kernel they most certainly, in a few cases, make use of status flags on return, but not in user space.)

Now there is one other state that is very funky in an Intel processor. If you are writing code that makes use of MMX registers, it is not compatible with the FPU. You have to use the EMMS instruction before you return to restore the state of the FPU (so the FPU actually works!) And you may have to save / restore the FPU registers. (i.e. if you have a function that uses the FPU calling a function using MMX, then on return the expected floating points are likely invalid unless you protected those...) Anyway, you should be using SSE instead.

P.S. the instruction mentioned by Netch is for optimization purposes where the compiler can assume (or not) that flags have not changed. I do not know that it is really used much though (it's probably too easy to make a mistake on that one.)

Answer (score 3):

For GCC, the logic is quite straight - one shall describe side effects of his code, and this includes "cc" to indicate flags are changed. The example which makes nothing but illustrate the method:

```
    asm("clc" : : : "cc");
```

A compiler will detect this and check if it need some flags and how.

But if you change more than condition code flags (e.g. DF) you should restore them after the action.

Sorry, I can't say anything on VS assembler except it was looking inconsistent all its life (no explicit inputs/outputs/effects declaration) and has finally removed from ix64 versions.

Comment: `removed from ix64`: Good riddance. Was rather buggy anyway.